# In GNOME on Wayland, how can I issue a command to reset the idle time?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, suspend

I know I can issue this command to get the Idle Time

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor /org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor.GetIdletime
```

, but how can I issue a command to reset this time, as in simulating user activity?

I've found this command

```
dbus-send --session --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver --type=method_call /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.SimulateUserActivity
```

, but it didn't do anything to the idle time.

I'm testing this on Ubuntu 23.04, GNOME and GDM on Wayland.

Comment: There is a method `org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor.ResetIdletime`, but it is for testing only and not compiled in by default. You might try looking a `ydotool` (wayland replacement for xdotool) to simulate a mouse or keyboard action.

Answer (score 1):

With `gnome-session-inhibit` you can set an inhibitor to prevent suspend, idle and some more. You can test this with `gnome-session-inhibit --reason "wait just 20 sec" --inhibit suspend sleep 20` which sets an inhibitor for 20 seconds.